# Command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: visual-studio-2017, cl

I am getting the warning message "cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release" while building my project with Visual Studio 2017 latest update 15.9.2. How to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try selecting `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` for the `Enable Minimal Rebuild` option (under `C/C++` > `Code Generation`). After this, the option should show `No (/Gm-)`, **not** in bold. Make sure you do this for your project(s) (you could have several projects in the solution), and all property pages they inherit from.

I had the same problem using Visual Studio 2019, in the end the problem was in a second project I had in the same solution, that had the option set to `Yes (/Gm)`.

Comment: For me, whenever I set `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` for the `Enable Minimal Rebuild` option, Visual Studio would set this to `Yes (/Gm)` for `Debug|x64`. But for `Release|x64` it would set it to `No (/Gm)` as expected. I trailed this down to `Project/PropertyGroup/UseDebugLibraries` in the .vcxproj. Deleting that node (not that that's the "correct" thing to do), makes it so the default value for `Enable Minimal Rebuild` is `No (/Gm-)`.

Answer (score 13):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gm-enable-minimal-rebuild?view=vs-2017)

> You may safely remove this option from your projects.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, I have Modified the "Enable Minimal Rebuild" property as per the documentation but still I am getting the same warning?

Comment: What kind of VCXPROJ are you using? Are you using the Makefile or Visual Studio build version?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I am using Visual Studio build version

Comment: This option may be set on specific file, so check on compilation of which file warning is shown

Answer (score 9):

[image: project property "Enable Minimal Rebuild" image]

`Project` > `Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `C\C++` > `Code Generation` >
set the `Enable Minimal Rebuild` to `no`, and there is no warning.

Comment: It's not resolving my problem

Comment: @AshishRathi: Setting it to "**bold** no" adds the option `/Gm-`. You want to delete the option altogether ("inherit from parent"), **and** there should not be a parent which has either `/Gm` or `/Gm-`.

Answer (score 6):

Happened for me too. Did not manage to fix it through UI.
In the end I searched for "MinimalRebuild" in all project files and removed it manually - that helped

Comment: I have experienced the same issue.

Comment: This was the only way it was fixed for me.

Comment: This did not work for me (Visual Studio 2017).  Manually removed all "MinimalRebuild" tags in the project files, still seeing the warning.

Answer (score 5):

Properties > C\C++ > Code Generation > Enable Minimal Rebuild: DELETE value - and there is no warning.

Comment: @Ashish: Have you made sure you've selected "All Configurations" and "All Platforms" on the project's property page, before changing the value...?

Answer (score 0):

UI did not work for me either. In the .vcxproj file search: "MinimalRebuild" I had missed a second one under Debug|Win32

Comment: To expand on this, this was most likely due to not have the "all configurations" option selected from the dropdown in the project settings window. You might already know this but just mentioning it in case others are wondering why you had to go into the project file source.

Answer (score -2):

just add this above your deprecated function

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4996);
```

example

```
#pragma warning (disable : 4996);
your_deprecated_function();
```