# Getting irelevant warning about option 'Gm' is deprecated

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Options I use to compile my project:

```
/JMC /GS /analyze- /Wall /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Od /sdl /Fd"Dev\Project.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MTd /FC /Fa"Dev\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Dev\" /Fp"Dev\Project.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

As you can see, there is not any `Gm` option. Anyways I'm getting this warning every time:

```
1>cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
1>cl : Command line warning D9007: '/Gm' requires '/Zi or /ZI'; option ignored
```

Problem is that `Gm` is disabled on every configuration. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53493622/1918193

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493622/command-line-warning-d9035-option-gm-has-been-deprecated-and-will-be-removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in UI. There was `<MinimalRebuild Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Dev|Win32'">true</MinimalRebuild>` in the `.vcxproj` file, but UI have been showing that field is blank. The warning is not there once I have deleted this from `.vcxproj`.